# Summarizing and Splitting Up Table into a Different Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have this table which looks like this:

```
user_id  location  duration(s)
-------  --------  -----------
1        room1     75
2        room1     289
1        room2     630
1        room1     287
```

The table above shows how long a user has been in a room, and the number of rows indicates how many times the user has been in a specific room. So for example in the above data, there are 2 rows in which user 1 was in location room1, meaning he has been in room1 twice. How would I go about taking this data in turning it into the table below:

```
user_id  room_1_freq  room_1_duration  room_2_freq  room_2_duration
-------  -----------  ---------------  -----------  ---------------
1        2            181              1            630
2        1            289              0            0
```

In which room_1_freq and room_2_freq is the number of times the user has been in the respective rooms, and room_1_duration and room_2_duration is the **average** time that the user spends in each room. Can this be done in a single query?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is just conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id,
       sum(location = 'room1') as room1_freq,
       sum(case when location = 'room1' then duration else 0 end) as room1_dur,
       sum(location = 'room2') as room2_freq,
       sum(case when location = 'room2' then duration else 0 end) as room1_dur
from t
group by user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler (and probably more flexible way) of answering your question.  Your secondary (results) table will extend exponentially with the number of columns for every room and every user that you need to report on and would, in my opinion, become difficult to manage. Plus, using Gordon's solution, you would have to rewrite your query every time a user or room were added.

It would be much easier to maintain if you summarised the data using standard sum, count and average functions within SQL with standard grouping clauses:

```
SELECT user_id, location, count(location), sum(duration), avg(duration) 
FROM visits
group by user_id, location
```

This would give you the results you wish, but in a slightly different format:

[image: Sum, count and average function use in SQL]

Doing it this way, you can add however many rooms and users you wish, and the summary info will always work.  Adding date or time columns to filter results would also be very easy.